# Probability and stochastic processes book for (PDE) analyst

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

I'm looking for some reference to improve my background knowledge in probability theory and stochastic processes.

I've been recommended to read Stromberg's book *Probability For Analysts*, which does seem suitable for my aims.

- Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I've had good luck with [Grimmett and Stirzaker](https://smile.amazon.com/Probability-Random-Processes-Geoffrey-Grimmett/dp/0198572220/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1492946960&sr=1-1)

Comment: "Probability Theory: An Analytic View" of Daniel W. Stroock

Comment: Durrett has some good, popular books on these topics.